# How to select listviewitem programmatically to behave like selecting with mouse/keyboard

Tags: wpf, listview

I'm trying to mimic the behavior of selection event in ListView using code. So here's the example code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="buttonSelectAbove" Content="Select Above"/>
    <Button x:Name="buttonSelectBelow" Content="Select Below"/>
    <ListView x:Name="listView"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and here's the code behind:

```
void buttonSelectBelow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    listView.SelectedIndex += 1;
    ListViewItem lvi = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listView.SelectedItem) as ListViewItem;
    if (lvi != null)
    {
        lvi.Focus();
    }
}

void buttonSelectAbove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    listView.SelectedIndex -= 1;
    ListViewItem lvi = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listView.SelectedItem) as ListViewItem;
    if (lvi != null)
    {
        lvi.Focus();
    }
}
```

now if you try those codes, clicking on each button and use keyboard to move up and down the list will work as expected, but when you use SHIFT click to select a range of items it will behave different with the selecting with mouse, here's some image to make it clearer:

**Normal selection behavior:**
clicking on C
[image]

and then shift click on E (will result in c, d, e to be selected)  [image]

**Selection via code behavior:**
clicking on A,
[image]

click button select below twice so C will be selected  [image]

and then shift click on E (it will result in a, b, c, d, e being selected)  [image]

so how do I achieve the normal selection behavior via code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListBox Shift-Click Multi-Select Anchor is not being set properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689987/listbox-shift-click-multi-select-anchor-is-not-being-set-properly)

Answer (score 0):

You use SelectionMode="Single" on LIstView if you dont like that it is able to select more than one row.

Comment: I want it to be able to multi select, it's just that the behavior of the SHIFT click after programmatic selection differ from the normal one.

Comment: Sounds like duplicate case of this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689987/listbox-shift-click-multi-select-anchor-is-not-being-set-properly

Comment: ahh yeah, didnt find that one because I dont know the right keyword to search, it looks like the 'multi-select anchor' is the key, thanks for the link